# Spark scalability

Tags: performance, apache-spark, scalability

I use currently one master (local machine) and two workers (2*32 cores, Memory 2*61.9 GB) for standard ALS algorithm of Spark and produce the next code for the time evaluation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
import random
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
import hashlib

#Spark configuration settings
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Temp").setMaster("spark://<myip>:7077").set("spark.cores.max","64").set("spark.executor.memory", "61g")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

#first time
t1 = time.time()

#load the DataFrame and transform it into RDD<Rating>
rddob = sqlContext.read.json("file.json").rdd
rdd1 = rddob.map(lambda line:(line.ColOne, line.ColTwo))
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda line: (line, 1))
rdd3 = rdd2.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
ratings = rdd3.map(lambda (line, rating): Rating(int(hash(line[0]) % (10 ** 8)), int(line[1]), float(rating)))
ratings.cache()

# Build the recommendation model using Alternating Least Squares
rank = 10
numIterations = 5
model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)

# Evaluate the model on training data
testdata = ratings.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))
predictions = model.predictAll(testdata).map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2]))
ratesAndPreds = ratings.map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2])).join(predictions)
MSE = ratesAndPreds.map(lambda r: (r[1][0] - r[1][1])**2).mean()
print("Mean Squared Error = " + str(MSE))

#second time
t2 = time.time()

#print results
print "Time of ALS",t2-t1
```

In this code I hold all parameters constant excepted parameter `set("spark.cores.max","x")` for which I use the next values for x: `1,2,4,8,16,32,64`. I got the next time evaluation:

```
#cores  time [s]
1       20722
2       11803
4       5596
8       3131
16      2125
32      2000
64      2051
```

The results of evaluation are a little bit strange for me. I see a good linear scalability by the small number of cores. But in the range of 16, 32 and 64 possible cores I don't see either any scalability, or improvement of time performance anymore. How is it possible? My input file is approximately 70 GB big and has 200 000 000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear scalability in distributed system like Spark is only in a small part a result of increasing number of cores. The most important part is opportunity to distribute disk / network IO. If you have constant number of workers and don't scale storage at the same time you'll quickly get to the point where throughput is limited by IO.